# How can i get html element names from a website url

Tags: java, apache-tika

I want to get HTML element names and attribute names (I don't want to use `documet.getElementsByTag("*")` or `document.select("*")`) without hard-coding.

Is there any chance to get HTML element names dynamically by using ***Apache Tika*** and, if possible, please provide me any sample example?

```
    Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://seenyc.co/").get();
            Elements elements=doc.getAllElements();
            for(Element ele:elements){


                String  s=ele.tagName();
                Attributes n=ele.attributes();
                System.out.println(s);
                System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: Of course, you can traverse the children through `childNodes`.

Comment: Can you please provide me sample  code for getting element names

Comment: No, you can search the API for yourself. Hint: nodes have *names*.

Comment: Actially,i tried with jsoup but i didn't find any method to get element names.I tried with DOM also but it is expectong for well formness

Comment: Srsly? http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#tag() RTFM!

Comment: i am able to get the elements.please find the code above. Suggest me any modification

Answer (score 2):

```
   HashSet<String> allTags=new HashSet<String>();
   Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://seenyc.co/").get();
            Elements elements=doc.getAllElements();
            for(Element ele:elements){
                String  s=ele.tagName();
                Attributes n=ele.attributes();
                allTags.add(s);
}

// here your hashset will have all distinct tag names from website
```

Is this what you wanted?